# Automatically redirect matched posts in Jekyll

Tags: redirect, github, jekyll

I recently move my website from Wordpress to Jekyll. At this time posts's urls changes according to date and so google indexed different from current one.

My url is structured as **baseurl/year/month/day/post_title**. I want to redirect from posts' different urls' to searched page automatically. The post_title is same but date is not. for example I have 
a post with Google indexed

http://webritmi.com/2018/01/01/apache-iis-tomtac-port-80-cakisma-sorunu-ve-cozumu

and I want to redirect it automatically to this one:

http://webritmi.com/2014/01/11/apache-iis-tomtac-port-80-cakisma-sorunu-ve-cozumu.

I have nearly 40 posts and I want to redirect them

> baseurl/2018/01/01/post_title

to

> baseurl/current_one_date/post_title

**current_one_date** is different and **all 40 posts's post title are same**.

Is there a basic way to redirect it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from

Comment: jekyll redirect can be a solution, but i dont want enter all possible redirect from url values in posts. i want to redirect an url to current url if title match. only date values different for same post url.

Comment: i cant find another solution yet, currently the best one is jekyll redirect from plugin as David offered.